# SqlServer, Transaction deadlock, when are table actually locked?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

This SQL (called from c#) occasionally results in a deadlock.
The server is not under much load so the approach used is to lock as much as possible.

```
   -- Lock to prevent race-conditions when multiple instances of an application calls this SQL:
        BEGIN TRANSACTION 
-- Check that no one has inserted the rows in T1 before me, and that T2 is in a valid state (Test1 != null)
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM T1 WITH(HOLDLOCK, TABLOCKX) WHERE FKId IN {0}) AND 
            NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM T2 WITH(HOLDLOCK, TABLOCKX) WHERE DbID IN {0} AND Test1 IS NOT NULL) 
            BEGIN
-- Great! Im the first - go insert the row in T1 and update T2 accordingly. Finally write a log to T3 
               INSERT INTO T1(FKId, Status) 
               SELECT DbId, {1} FROM T2 WHERE DbId IN {0}; 

               UPDATE T2 SET LastChangedBy = {2}, LastChangedAt = GETDATE() WHERE DbId IN {0}; 

               INSERT INTO T3 (F1, FKId, F3) 
               SELECT {2}, DbId, GETDATE() FROM T2 WHERE DbId IN {0} ;
            END; 

            -- Select status on the rows so the program can evaluate what just happened
            SELECT FKId, Status FROM T1 WHERE FkId IN {0}; 

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I believe the problem is that multiple tables needs to be locked.

I'm a bit unsure when the tables are actually xlocked - when a table is used the first time - or are all tables locked at one time at BEGIN TRANS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locks are done when you call lock or select with lock and released on commit or rollback.

You could get a dead lock if another procedure locks in T3 first and in T1 or T2 afterwards. Then two transactions are waiting for each other to get a resource, while locking what the other needs.

You could also avoid the table lock and use isolation level serializable.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the serializable mode.  Finer grained row level locks re less susceptible to deadlocks.

Comment: Yes, table locks are actually a rather bad thing performance wise, but if it is the only solution to make things work properly, well, then it is a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using Table Locks can increase the likelihood of getting deadlocks... Not all deadlocks are caused by out of sequence operations...  Some can be caused, (as you have found) by other activity that only tries to lock a single record in the same table you are locking completely, so locking the entire table increases the probability for that conflict to occur.  When using serializable isolation level, range locks are placed on index rows, which can prevent inserts/deletes by other sql operations, in a way that can cause a deadlock by two concurrent operations from the same procedure, even though they are coded to perform their ops in the same order...

In any event, to find out what exactly is causing the deadlock, set SQL Server Trace flags 1204 and 1222.  These will cause detailed info to be written to the SQL Server Logs about each deadlock, including what statements were involved.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx) is a good article about how to do this.

(Don't forget to turn these flags off when you're done...)

Comment: in addition if this is sql server 2005 you can use profiler to log deadlocks & it draws pretty diagrams for you

Answer (score 0):

The problem with locking is that you really need to look at all places you do locking at the same time, there's no way to isolate and split up the problem into many smaller ones and look at those individually.

For instance, what if some other code locks the same tables, but without it being obvious, and in the wrong order? That'll cause a deadlock.

You need to analyze the server state at the moment the deadlock is discovered to try to figure out what else is running at the moment. Only then can try to fix it.